# Anaconda Kernel and Google Colab crash when using cv2.FastFeatureDetector()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am trying to use the cv2.FastFeatureDetector() method and everytime i run this code to extract features my kernel in both Google Collab and Anaconda crashes for some reason. Initially I thought it was memory management issue with my system, but the same thing is happening in Colab.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    image=cv2.imread('tree.jpg',0)
    fast=cv2.FastFeatureDetector()
    keypoints=fast.detect(image,None)
    #After running this code my kernel crashes
```

There is no error message due to the kernel crash.
The image is fairly small in size and not that computationally expensive.
Here is the image:
https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Sun-Tree-Branches-1920-x-1080.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. With newer OpenCV versions you have to create your detector via `fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()`. Note that you might have to adjust the rest of your code due to other API changes.